# Drawing opencv?

Tags: c++, video, opencv, drawing

How would I draw a CvBox2D in OpenCV?
Is there any similar function to cvRectangle?

CODE EXAMPLES WOULD BE APPRECIATED

Thanks

Comment: if there is cvRectangle function ,then why u want similar ???

Comment: because cvRectangle is only for rectangles
cvBox2D is not compatible with cvRectangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a function like cvRectangle for CvBox2D. This is the structure of CvBox2D:

```
typdef struct {
CvPoint2D32f center;
CvSize2D32f size;
float angle;
} CvBox2D;
```

You can use cvBoxPoints to get the points of the rectangle and then draw the rectangle as a set of lines.

```
void cvBoxPoints(CvBox2D box, CvPoint2D32f pt[]);
```

You can even use cvPolyLine to draw the lines easier.

```
void cvPolyLine(CvArr* img, CvPoint** pts, int* npts, int contours, int isClosed, CvScalar color, int thickness=1, int lineType=8, int shift=0 )
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but only one of my CvBox2D is showing up. Any idea why? (I used cvPolyLine and cvBoxPoints twice on two different boxes)

Comment: If you post some of your code here or on another question maybe I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Function to draw rotated rect in iplimage.

```
void DrawRotatedRect( IplImage * iplSrc,CvBox2D rect,CvScalar color, int thickness CV_DEFAULT(1),int line_type CV_DEFAULT(8), int shift CV_DEFAULT(0));

void DrawRotatedRect( IplImage * iplSrc,CvBox2D rect,CvScalar color, int thickness, int line_type, int shift )  
{   
CvPoint2D32f boxPoints[4];
cvBoxPoints(rect, boxPoints);
cvLine(iplSrc,cvPoint((int)boxPoints[0].x, (int)boxPoints[0].y),cvPoint((int)boxPoints[1].x, (int)boxPoints[1].y),color,thickness,line_type,shift);
cvLine(iplSrc,cvPoint((int)boxPoints[1].x, (int)boxPoints[1].y),cvPoint((int)boxPoints[2].x, (int)boxPoints[2].y),color,thickness,line_type,shift);
cvLine(iplSrc,cvPoint((int)boxPoints[2].x, (int)boxPoints[2].y),cvPoint((int)boxPoints[3].x, (int)boxPoints[3].y),color,thickness,line_type,shift);
cvLine(iplSrc,cvPoint((int)boxPoints[3].x, (int)boxPoints[3].y),cvPoint((int)boxPoints[0].x, (int)boxPoints[0].y),color,thickness,line_type,shift);   
}
```